# How to color Excel Headers cells using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to create an excel file. I am using short hand notation to create cells and I want to know if there is a way to fill the colors on the cells using the same coding pattern.

Coding standard 1.

```
Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
 headerRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(NYPG3Constants.FIRST_NAME);
 headerRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(NYPG3Constants.LAST_NAME);
 headerRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(NYPG3Constants.POLICY_NUMBER);
 headerRow.createCell(3).setCellValue(NYPG3Constants.ZIP_CODE);
 headerRow.createCell(4).setCellValue(NYPG3Constants.DATE_OF_BIRTH);
```

I can set styles using following coding pattern but for every cell headers I need to create a separate cell object.

Coding standard 2

```
CellStyle style = workBook.createCellStyle();
 style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GOLD.index);
 style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

 Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(0);
 cell.setCellValue(NYPG3Constants.FIRST_NAME);
 cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Is there a way to fill colors on the header cells using my first coding standard?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a simple `for` loop?

```
CellStyle style = workBook.createCellStyle();
 style.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.GOLD.index);
 style.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

...

Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
 headerRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(NYPG3Constants.FIRST_NAME);
 headerRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(NYPG3Constants.LAST_NAME);
 headerRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(NYPG3Constants.POLICY_NUMBER);
 headerRow.createCell(3).setCellValue(NYPG3Constants.ZIP_CODE);
 headerRow.createCell(4).setCellValue(NYPG3Constants.DATE_OF_BIRTH);

for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
 headerRow.getCell(c).setCellStyle(style);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Axel. It does what I am looking for. Appreciated.